# Linking function from controller scope in directive scope

Tags: angularjs

I've wrote a directive that should emulate the AngularJS-DataTable.
In this case I need to execute some function on the last `<td>` since they're buttons. I don't want to pass the functions to the directive to keep the directive as independet as possible.

So in this case, when I specify "renderable" on a data, and a "render" function, if it got a ng-click I need that function, defined in the controller, to be executed, but when i Click on the buttons, nothing happens.

This is the data I've in my Controller, with the function "print()" that I need to call from the directive

```
$scope.print = function(){
    console.log("It worked!");
};

$scope.tableData = {
    data: data.response,
    columns: [{
                title:"",
                data: "priority",
                renderable: true,
                render: function(data){
                    return "<span class='btn btn-xs fa fa-fw fa-angle-down' ng-click='lowerPriority()'></span>";
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Nome Servizio",
                data: "title"
            },
            {
                title: "Descrizione",
                data: "description",
                renderable: true,
                render: function(data, row){
                    var html = "<div ng-click='print()'>"+row.sum+"</div>";
                    return html;
                }
            },
        ],
    }
```

In my page I'm calling

```
<smart-table data="tableData" ></smart-table>
```

And then in my directive template

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data.data | filter: search.value" repeat-done>
    <td ng-repeat="cell in data.columns">
        <span ng-if="cell.renderable" ng-bind-html="trustHtml(cell.render(row[cell.data], row))"></span>
        <span ng-if="!cell.renderable">{{row[cell.data]}}</span>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Lastly, this is my directive

```
var smartTable = angular.module('smartTable', ['ngSanitize']);

smartTable.directive('smartTable',['$compile', '$sce', '$templateRequest', function($compile, $sce, $templateRequest) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/public/components/directives/smartTable.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentScope) {

        scope.trustHtml = function(data){
            var template = angular.element(data);
            elem.append(template);
            // $compile(angular.element(data))(scope);
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        };

        $templateRequest('/public/components/directives/smartTable.tpl.html').then(function(html){

            console.log(scope);
            scope.$watch(attrs.data, function(elemasd) {
                var template = angular.element(html);
                elem.append(template);
                elem.html(html);
                scope.data = scope[attrs.data];
                $compile(elem)(scope);
              });

        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: make a fiddle/plnkr if possible

Comment: i was trying to, managed to obtain http://plnkr.co/edit/VMDdSlHHPQFzFT8vDyYz only. But this doesn't even shows the table

Answer (score 0):

Ater your template slightly to use $last, if you're looking for the last td:

```
<td ng-if="$last" ng-click="vm.print()"></td>
```

Comment: It's not what I asked, sorry if I wasn't clear. My problem is that in the rendered cell I got a "ng-click" that's not working. It's not calling my controller's print function

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this bind your function

```
 smartTable.directive('smartTable',['$compile', '$sce', '$templateRequest', function($compile, $sce, $templateRequest) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {data: '=',
                print: '&'},
        templateUrl: '/public/components/directives/smartTable.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentScope) {

            scope.trustHtml = function(data){
                var template = angular.element(data);
                elem.append(template);
                // $compile(angular.element(data))(scope);
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
            };

            $templateRequest('/public/components/directives/smartTable.tpl.html').then(function(html){

                console.log(scope);
                scope.$watch(attrs.data, function(elemasd) {
                    var template = angular.element(html);
                    elem.append(template);
                    elem.html(html);
                    scope.data = scope[attrs.data];
                    $compile(elem)(scope);
                  });

            });
        }
      };
    }]);
```

HTML

```
<smart-table data="tableData" print="print"></smart-table>
```

Comment: I need to keed the directive more unbinded to the controller. I need to reuse this directive in various controller and each one got different situation. Some controller got no buttons/functions, some got 2-3 of them. I need it to stay as independent as possible